# Initial scene in BGE

Tags: game-engine

Is there a way to set the initial scene in Blender Game Engine so it always starts at the beginning, regardless of what scene you have selected in the editor?

I hate having to go up to the top, and use the drop-down to select the right scene, every time I run it.

Comment: If you save your blend while in the scene you want next time you opend the blend will start blender with that scene.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not talking about when loading the .blend file.  Let's say I have Main & GameOver scenes, and I'm editing GameOver.  Do I have to switch back to Main every time I press P to play, or can Blender jump back to Main for me?

Comment: I guess you could write a script that does switches scene and starts the game engine.

Comment: That's a possibility.  Was hoping Blender had a built-in method.  As it is, I set a key-sensor on the P key, so once it runs I can tap P again and it'll jump to the Main scene ...which works, but feels gimmicky.

Answer (score 1):

When I use an overlay scene I use this method:

The level scene adds the overlay scene as overlay.
The overlay scene adds the level scene as background.

The BGE does not add an already loaded scene. Therefore you always get both scenes regardless what scene was the first one.

Attention: this will not work when you want to use the overlay scene with another level scene.

Comment: When i say GameOver, I don't mean overlay.  That's the scene that shows up when the game ends.  I want Blender to automatically switch back to the beginning.